# How to get multiple records in SWT table

Tags: java, swt

I want to create a table using SWT, and want to add a column with checkbox, then I want to delete the rows which were checked (the checkboxes were checked).

I know how to add a column with checkbox, like following:

```
TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(table);
final Button checkButton = new Button(table, SWT.CHECK);
```

but I don't know how to get the selected rows (the checkbox were checked). I researched it using google, but haven't found a demo, can anybody tell me how to get the selected rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, create your table with the `SWT.CHECK` flag, so you don't need to create Buttons.

Second, when you do this, you can use TableItem's `getChecked()` method to retrive the check state.